# The 19.10 version works slow on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows, 19.10

My host system is Windows 10.
I use ubuntu on my laptop with 16GB memory and i7 last 3 years, and always updates ubuntu to latest release. So this week I was install 19.10 and it works too slow than 19.04.

Any ideas how to improve performance?

UPD: it is the guest in VB. Latest VB 6.0.14 r133895 (Qt5.6.2). CPU and the Memory the same as I used for 19.04. 4Gb memory, and 4 from 8 processors.
[image]

Comment: Is Ubuntu running as a guest in VB, or in WSL? What version VB? What CPU COUNT and MEMORY settings in VB? Edit your question and show me `free -h`.

Comment: @heynnema, thanks for questions I updated info

Comment: My observations: The latest VB is 6.1.x. Your swap is excessive. For testing purposes, try changing your CPU count to 2 and see the effects.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for hint, I updated VB and everything return to normal way

Answer (score 1):

I miss 6.1.x release, under it it work as fast as I expected, without any additional changes. Thanks [heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) for hint.